# MS Access Database form not updating after SQL requery

Tags: sql, forms, ms-access, report, refresh

I have a report that runs from a query.  The query does use a global variable but this is not the problem but needed for the explanation.  The function for the variable is:

```
Function Var1() As String
    Var1 = strVar1
End Function
```

The query where statement is:

```
WHERE (((IIf([MinOfDueDayMin]<0,0,Int([MinOfDueDayMin]/7)+1))<Var1()+1) AND ((tblEquipment.Retired)=False))
```

which uses the var1 function

The criteria is on a field that is actually a calculation and that is where I think the problem starts.

The report is run for a command on another form using the following code:

```
strVar1 = InputBox("Enter Number of Weeks for report")
If strVar1 = "" Then Exit Sub
DoCmd.OpenReport "rptEquipPmSchedule", acViewReport
```

Everything works just fine

On the report I have a double click event that opens a form.  This form uses part of the same query.  (not the same one but two levels higher)  thiS allow the user to change things so i expect to use requery for the report.

If i double click and then not even change anything and then go back to the report I have #ERROR in the fields that have the calculations

i put a me.requery in the activate event of the report.  this did not work.

So I tried a work around.

When I double click the report field, i close the report and send the strVar1 value to the form that is opened.  then when I close the form I reasign the strVar1 just in case it is lost be an assignment by another user (currently I am the only one using this but did it just to be sure it had the correct value.) Then I open the report again but still get the errors.  I did not expect this at all.  thought starting the report from scratch would certainly work.  I even closed the form just after assigning strVar1.

then in final effort.  When I close the form I run the exact same code:

```
strVar1 = InputBox("Enter Number of Weeks for report")
If strVar1 = "" Then Exit Sub
DoCmd.OpenReport "rptEquipPmSchedule", acViewReport
```

Which will force the user to input the value for strVal1. Even though this is not what I want but tried this for troubleshooting and I still get #ERROR.

When I run the report for a form that does not have any of the same field, no issues.  When I run the report or keep it open with a requery from the form that has the same data, the report will not give the correct results.  Note that if I run the query itself, the data in the query is correct.

i also tried using a number instead of Val1() in the query and got the same results.

i also tried the refresh button in the ribbon and get Unknown Function Name and all the data in the report is lost.

Anyone got any ideas??

Answer (score 0):

While your textual explanation is difficult to understand the entire scope, consider re-assessing your workflow. The entire objective is to allow users to run customized criteria for reporting. And your main issue is the *strVal* does not persist in memory so all references to it fails.

Consider the following points:

- Have users set criteria on a dedicated unbound form with button click for report where that report instance is immutable for viewing/printing only and if needed to be changed must be re-run (i.e., button re-clicked).
- Access has no need for VBA's `InputBox()` as *strVal* can be an unbound textbox on this unbound form whose value remains intact for all open windows.
- Have function and all its references point to form field: `Form!myFormName!strValuetextbox`
- Because reports on pretty much any software/web app system is not used as a GUI interface to run actions, users will know if they intend to change report criteria, close current report or go back to entry point and change *strVal* then re-click button to re-run report.
- Keep data entry/input (primary use of forms) separate from data export/output (like reports). From developer and user standpoint this compartmentalization will save you headaches down the road.

Comment: The problem isn't keeping the value of strVal1.

Comment: I will try explaining differently as I obviously didn't explain well.   The problem isn't keeping the value of strVal1, although I do like your idea of using a form that stays open to maintain the value as an option.  I want to run a report.  If the user sees info in the report and wants to edit it then I want to give the option to double click the serial number (the unique id) that open a form and allows editing.

Comment: then when complete he closes the form and I want the report to update with the new info and do not want the user to have to enter the value of strVal1.  But even when entering it again I get #ERROR when the report is run again or re-queried.